# MAX() retornando várias linhas

Tags: sql, oracle

Ao rodar o script o mesmo não me retorna apenas o valor máximo, ou seja, o maior horário, mas sim os 3 horários.

```
SELECT  P.CD_PACIENTE CD_PACIENTE
            ,P.NM_PACIENTE NM_PACIENTE
            ,L.CD_UNID_INT CD_UNID_INT
            ,L.DS_ENFERMARIA DS_ENFERMARIA
            ,L.DS_LEITO DS_LEITO
            ,MAX(MI.HR_MOV_INT) HR_MOV_INT


            FROM ATENDIME A
            JOIN PACIENTE P ON P.CD_PACIENTE = A.CD_PACIENTE
            JOIN MOV_INT MI ON MI.CD_ATENDIMENTO = A.CD_ATENDIMENTO
            JOIN LEITO L ON L.CD_LEITO = MI.CD_LEITO

            WHERE A.DT_ALTA_MEDICA IS NULL
            AND P.CD_PACIENTE = 0

            GROUP BY P.CD_PACIENTE 
            ,P.NM_PACIENTE 
            ,L.CD_UNID_INT
            ,L.DS_ENFERMARIA 
            ,L.DS_LEITO

            ORDER BY P.CD_PACIENTE
```

**Resultado retornado:**

```
0   TESTE   35  0319    VIRTUAL     11/06/2018 10:51:18
0   TESTE   23  0414    LEITO03     11/06/2018 10:49:48
0   TESTE   35  0319    LEITO008    01/04/2018 16:00:00
```

**Resultado esperado:**

```
0   TESTE   35  0319    VIRTUAL     11/06/2018 10:51:18
```

Answer (score 3):

Ele vai trazer o MAX dentro do seu agrupamento, está correto.Caso você queira olhar o MAX de toda a tabela, deixe somente o MAX no select. Novamente, caso você deixe o agrupamento ele sempre vai mostrar o resultado máximo dentro de cada agrupamento. Não sei se consegui ser claro.

Comment: Sendo assim, como posso resolver esse caso? Tirando as colunas da tabela LEITO e colocando elas em um subselect fora do agrupamento?

Answer (score 1):

Quando você utiliza `group by`, ele faz o agrupamento em cada valor da coluna que você específica, ou seja, agrupa valores iguais, veja nesse [exemplo](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_select_groupby).

Quando você utiliza o `max()`, ele retorna o campo de maior valor da coluna, ou seja, retorna o campo maior, veja nesse [exemplo](https://www.w3schools.com/SQl/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_select_max).

Se você utiliza o `group by` juntamente com o `max()`, o resultado irá retornar o valor máximo de cada agrupamento que você pede específica, não um único valor. Se você deseja pegar o maior valor, retire o agrupamento dos valores, para retornar um única linha.

Answer (score 1):

Olá,

Conforme os colegas citaram cima, está correto retornarem os três valores. A forma mais fácil de contornar isso, partindo do princípio de que você já tem o select pronto, é colocá-lo no from na forma de um subselect e fora dele chamar a função MAX.

Assim:

```
    SELECT MAX(TAB.HR_MOV_INT) -- demais colunas desejadas
     FROM
    (SELECT  P.CD_PACIENTE CD_PACIENTE
        ,P.NM_PACIENTE NM_PACIENTE
        ,L.CD_UNID_INT CD_UNID_INT
        ,L.DS_ENFERMARIA DS_ENFERMARIA
        ,L.DS_LEITO DS_LEITO
        ,MAX(MI.HR_MOV_INT) HR_MOV_INT

        FROM ATENDIME A
        JOIN PACIENTE P ON P.CD_PACIENTE = A.CD_PACIENTE
        JOIN MOV_INT MI ON MI.CD_ATENDIMENTO = A.CD_ATENDIMENTO
        JOIN LEITO L ON L.CD_LEITO = MI.CD_LEITO

        WHERE A.DT_ALTA_MEDICA IS NULL
        AND P.CD_PACIENTE = 0

        GROUP BY P.CD_PACIENTE 
        ,P.NM_PACIENTE 
        ,L.CD_UNID_INT
        ,L.DS_ENFERMARIA 
        ,L.DS_LEITO) tab
```

Comment: Não adiantou, ele me força mesmo assim a fazer um group by e quando faço esse group by tenho que colocar o cd_leito ai ele trás tudo de novo. Mas Obrigado pela ajuda e desculpe a demora!